# Binding Canvas images to events based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have the following fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tbt0jspd/2/

The idea is to display a series of boxes on the screen using the box image that will have a class of `box` on them but ONE will have a class of `win` and the rest will have a class of `lose`.

This is how I handle adding the boxes to the canvas element:

```
var boxes = 6;

var boxImg = new Image();

boxImg.src = 'img/box.png';

boxImg.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 0, x = 20, y = 200; i < boxes; x += 148, y = 200, i++) {
        context.drawImage(boxImg, x, y);
    }
};
```

The first question is h**ow do I add the classes as described above to the images?** They should all have a class of box, and 5 should have a class of lose, and 1 a class of win.

Users will then click these boxes and a class of opened will be applied to them in turn. The boxes will change to a different image depending on their class of win or lose.

```
$('.box').not('.opened').on('click', function() {

    if( $(this).hasClass('win') ) {

        $(this).src = 'img/box-win.png';

    } else if( $(this).hasClass('lose') ) {

        $(this).src = 'img/box-lose.png';

    }

    $(this).addClass('opened');

    if( $('.opened').length == boxes )
    {
        alert('all boxes open');
    }

});
```

Comment: If you are planning to click on the boxes, you might not want to use a canvas but just <div> and or <img/>

Answer (score 1):

You can't have classes on boxes that or on canvas, because after you draw an image on canvas, it becomes nothing more but a set of pixels.

What you can do, however, is modify which image gets drawn on the canvas based on its class (or another property), but you'll have to redraw it on the canvas whenever it's changed.

Redrawing them on canvas is the key.

For easier control, you might consider using an object to represent boxes (not just their images), so you can easily toggle their states/images/etc.

---

UPDATE

Here is a simple example using the button to open all the boxes and assign them win/lose state randomly: http://jsfiddle.net/d7ov9pak/

```js
    var boxes = 6;
    var canvas = document.getElementById('OpenTheBox');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var boxImg = new Image();
    boxImg.src = 'http://i59.tinypic.com/vqp4c7.png';
    var winImg = new Image();
    winImg.src = 'http://i60.tinypic.com/2ujtr0i.png';
    var loseImg = new Image();
    loseImg.src = 'http://i60.tinypic.com/oivsc0.png';
    var cwidth = canvas.width = window.screen.width;
    var cheight = canvas.height = window.screen.height;
    var ctop = canvas.offsetTop;
    var cleft = canvas.offsetLeft;
    context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, cwidth, cheight);

    canvas.oncontextmenu = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    boxImg.onload = function () {
        for (var i = 0, x = 20, y = 200; i < boxes; x += 148, y = 200, i++) {
            context.drawImage(boxImg, x, y);
        }
    };



    function openBoxes() {
        // clear the canvas, just in case
        canvas.width = canvas.width;
        for (var i = 0, x = 20, y = 200; i < boxes; x += 148, y = 200, i++) {
            // assign a random win/lose box
            var image = (Math.random() >= 0.5) ? winImg : loseImg;
            context.drawImage(image, x, y);
        }
    }
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openBoxes()">Open the boxes</button>
<canvas id="OpenTheBox"></canvas>
```

Note, if this is all there is to it and you don't need any other canvas functionality, perhaps you should consider not using the canvas, and simply manipulate DOM element to show different images based on CSS classes.

Comment: Think you could whip up a quick example?

Comment: I'll try, but I'll probably have to change quite a few things.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I need the click events on each box rather than open them all. How would I do that and still handle the win/lose?

Comment: You can set a click listener on the canvas, and then watch for coordinates of the event and see if they match with any of the boxes, and then handle just that one box.

Comment: That seems really crappy. Surely all the games out there that are written in HTML5 canvas are not just matching coords like that and actually contain objects you can interact with?

Comment: Unfortunately, they are (at least that's how the click handling starts). Canvas is a single element and has no idea what's drawn inside it. So the click starts on the canvas element, and is then handled by the code. There are probably helper libraries for this, but that's the process. That's why I suggested you do this without canvas if you don't need any specific canvas functionality. See this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-games/

Comment: @Cameron Upvote...as Shomz says, canvas games really do listen for events on the canvas and then tie those events into individual drawings on the canvas. Think of the canvas as a low level element where nearly infinite variations are possible, but you must do everything yourself. You might consider using SVG which actually adds elements to the DOM so you could listen for events on individual drawings. The DOM doesn't get overwhelmed until you add hundreds of svg components so svg might be better in your case. Just a thought... :-)